# xmlstarlet unable to read file location variable

Tags: xml, linux, bash, xmlstarlet

I have run into a strange issue with the **xmlstarlet** utility
Whenever I run

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//email' demofilename.xml
```

It returns the all the emails found within the file with no issues.

However When I replace the filename with a dynamic variable containing the filepath  as given below, it fails.

```
myfilepath=/root/demofilename.xml
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//email' "$myfilepath"
```

It returns with the following message.

```
*Wherever file name mentioned in command help it is assumed
that URL can be used instead as well.

Type: xmlstarlet <command> --help <ENTER> for command help*
```

My Xml Version is given as below:-
Running this on Kali linux os 2018 on bash shell 4.4 version.

```
xmlstarlet --version
1.6.1
compiled against libxml2 2.9.4, linked with 20904
compiled against libxslt 1.1.29, linked with 10129
```

Would appreciate if someone could assist me with this madness...

Comment: `$myfilepath` -> `"$myfilepath"`

Comment: Tried that too , dont seem to work at all

Comment: The path does expand properly , but still no luck.

Comment: Is that a truncated message? The [full one here](https://sourceforge.net/p/xmlstar/code/ci/master/tree/src/usage.txt) has more text. What's the output from `printf '[%s]\n' xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//email' "$myfilepath"` and `file "$myfilepath"`?

Comment: check the permissions - in the variable you are referencing a file in /root directory, not in the current directory, as in your working example

Comment: Thanks dr_argon - that solved the issue.